# C - Advantages of dynamically allocating a single struct

Tags: c, struct

I have been browsing some C code recently and noticed that some people write functions to dynamically allocate and initialise C structs, e.g.

```
struct pool {
    /* ... */
};

struct pool *pool_new(/* ... */)
{
     struct pool *p = calloc(1, sizeof(*p));
     /* initialise p ... */
     return p;
}
```

I am unsure if this is good practice as this kind of definition enforces the use of dynamic allocation and may lead to unnecessary memory fragmentation. I know this is probably the way to define opaque objects but i've seen this kind of code for "normal" structs as well. What are the advantages of this kind of practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One reason for dynamic over static allocation is portability of the object. A stack-allocated object can only be passed down the stack by pointer, never up, while a heap-allocated pointer can be passed around at will.

The stack is also generally smaller than the heap, so if the structures take up a lot of ram, it can be better to heap allocate them.

Using an allocation function also allows you to ensure that certain fields are filled in correctly, especially important if those fields are calculated from other values in the structure and you don't want to have to duplicate those calculations everywhere.

Comment: That's a great answer